# Is there any .NET structure or class for 3D Points which is compatible with mono?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, mono

I'm writing a application which is cross-platform.
There is already a structure at namespace `System::Windows::Media::Media3D::Point3D`.
The problem is that mono doesn't support `System::Windows` as part of project.

So I thought there might be structure or class for this purpose.
No matter if it's built-in or not.
I can also attach extensions as part of my project if the extension is light-weight and portable.
The only important thing is to be cross-platform.

Comment: Do you just need a structure to store points (in which case I'd point [pun not intended] to [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)), or do you need to perform geometric operations?

Comment: struct Point3D { public double x; public double y; public double z; }

Comment: @SimpleCoder I do need geometric operations. Not only for 3D Points but also for Quards.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116717/cross-platform-graphics-3d-with-net be overkill?

Comment: @SimpleCoder As I mentioned I can attach extensions but should be light-weight and portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Vector3` or `Vector4`.  They both store floats (X, Y, Z) and (W, X, Y, Z), respectively.

Comment: I do need geometric operations. Not only for 3D Points but also for Quards

Comment: @Mahdi - not sure which operations you need, but they both support matrix math.

Comment: @Mahdi - there's also `Quaternion`, which has W, X, Y, Z.

Comment: `Vector3D` is part of `System::Windows::Media::Media3D` which is NOT supported by mono.

Comment: @Mahdi - use `Vector3`, NOT `Vector3D`. The namespace for the types mentioned is `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`.

Comment: Do I need to install XNA Framework beside my project or is it portable ?

Comment: @Mahdi - Sorry, I think I am leading you down the wrong path here. When I first read "Mono", I thought you meant "Monogame". Yes, you will need either XNA or Monogame. Although Monogame is portable - http://monogame.net/

Comment: @Mahdi - Something I just thought of is that Monogame is open source. You might be able to grab just the class files that you need.

Comment: @Mahdi - Monogame uses the MS-PL license, you may want to check with a lawyer as to terms of use. Source code here: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame

Answer (score 0):

Unity3D is a cross platform 3D gaming environment which is based on Mono, which means that you can code the bits you need to in C#.

Mono Compatibility in [unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html)

> you can use .NET class libraries in the scripts you write for Unity.
>   Depending on your .NET Compatibility level selected in your project
>   settings.
>
> Unity supports more, or less of the full class libraries. This page
>   contains a list of which classes and methods are available for each
>   .NET compatibility level setting

Comment: @mahdi:did you used this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20385/3D-Geometry-Library-Basic-Classes-and-3D-Drawing-u? or use `vector3D` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d.aspx